# setting width of select tag not working

Tags: html, css, input, drop-down-menu

I've tried nearly EVERYTHING that could be found about this on stackoverflow
e.g.

```
<select style="width:50px;">
//all my select options and stuff would be here
```

&

```
<select class="pleasekillme">
//all my select options and stuff would be here

<style>
.pleasekillme {
width: 50px;
}
</style>
```

&

```
<select width="50">
//all my select options and stuff would be here
```

And I've tried a few more but **nothing** is working, please help.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Should work unless you have another CSS declaration overriding it (like using bootstrap perhaps). Try:  `.pleasekillme { width: 50px ! important; }`

Comment: The first should be work but if it is not then definitely some other styling overriding your styling.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me using

```
select {
 width: 500px;
}
```

Heres a simple JsFiddle of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/un67fLxa/

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your markup for errors? `width` on select tags should be working. You can use your browsers developer tools, if the `width` is overwritten by some other rules. In this case you can use `!important`, but that's not recommanded.

```css
.first {
  width: 100px;
}
.second {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select class="first">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select class="second">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) for more information about styling select tags.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem in background and borders. I think the only tricky part by far I experienced was the padding because of safari 5.1.7 in windows. Fortunately, we can just declare line-height and with if the browser is safari.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ewa59apq/

```
<select id="test">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

css

```
select {
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

Check if what's the width via js

```
var testing = document.getElementById('test');

alert(window.getComputedStyle(testing).getPropertyValue('width'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly chcek [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ag6wemng/).Try giving !important.

```
.pleasekillme {
   width: 50px !important;
 }
```